# Count the number of values in a column using a value in another column

Tags: mysql

```
+-------------+---------------+
|   order_no  |   product_id  |
|      55     |      765      |
|      55     |      564      |
|      34     |      323      |
|      42     |      223      |
+-------------+---------------+
```

I'd like to know a query that I could use to get the total number of order_no after using "765" as a product_id.

What I mean to say is that I want the output to be "2" because there are two products for order_no "55". So, if I input "765" in the query I would get "2".

Comment: Getting 2 as the result would be impossible, as the two products listed in order_no = 55 has different product IDs. My guess is that you would like to display the number of orders for a certain product ID?

Comment: @jaolstad: I think the idea is to use a `product_id` to identify an `order_no`, and then count the number of `product_id`s associated with that `order_no`, but not with a very high confidence level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eff29/4

```
SELECT 
t.product_id, 
t.order_no,
COUNT(tj.product_id)
FROM t1 t
LEFT JOIN t1 tj
ON t.order_no = tj.order_no
WHERE t.product_id=765
GROUP BY t.product_id, t.order_no
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. you can give a products_id :

```
SELECT COUNT(*), order_no FROM youTable
WHERE order_no IN (
  SELECT  order_no FROM yourTable WHERE  product_id = 765
)
GROUP BY order_no;
```